# How to get a store and column of a grid from xml

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I declare one grid in extjs 3.4. I am using ajax call and on success function I am getting column and data. How will I use this data as a store in grid.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.data.XmlStore and can refer docs to configure it.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlStore